# Details of Tick Tuple Schema

Tags: apache-storm

how to get the tick tuple schema?

Am assuming tick tuple would contain the timeout value...this would help the application to know/judge which timer has expired.

Comment: printed ticktuple.getlongbyfield(0)...it is giving the timer value.

Comment: strom does not support starting multiple tick timers. This needs to be simulated by  multiple bolts.